# measure download progress of large json in javascript w/ jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-chrome-extension

Is there any way to measure and keep track of the progress of downloading a large JSON file using getJSON, or something similar if that can't do it.
at the moment, since getJSON has basically only a success callback, i don't know what's going on until the json is done downloading. (upwards of a minute)

if it helps, this will be part of a standalone chrome app and a phonegap app

Comment: You need to send the data (regardless what the data is) in chunks from the server to the client and measure it in that way.There are related answers to that already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up following a guide at 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest
and using XMLHTTPRequests instead of getJSON

I also had to use some rack middleware on the ruby on rails side to include content-length in the HTTP response for JSON

Comment: This was my approach, but I simply could not get content length to show up. Hosting on Heroku