# Is the number of "records" in a json file known when calling .getJSON()?

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui, getjson, jquery-ui-progressbar

I want to use a jQueryUI progress bar when I'm reading a very large json file. Is the number of "records" in the file known when calling getJSON(), so that I can advance the progress bar accordingly?

Comment: What do you mean is the number of "records" known?

Comment: I suppose `records` is an array. Just check the length in the `success`/`done` and do stuff with the progressbar there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12876213/139010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not known.

When you call getJSON() commands an HTTP GET. If the response contains JSON, you must wait for the whole thing to load before you can parse it and count any possible "records".

What you can do, however, is to use [HTML5 Progress Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/progress-events/) to track the progress of your file upload, say, to display a progress bar. See for instance, [this tutorial](http://www.matlus.com/html5-file-upload-with-progress/).